# why auth is frequently implemented using 2 redirects

Tags: authentication, redirect, architecture, react-router

In web system, when some URL is protected, user is redirected to dedicated auth-page, and after login is (in convenient case) redirected back.

I understand that with mail.google.com and accounts.google.com the reason is huge google infrastructure, and may be different developer groups responsible for accounts and mail. And if I want to make user authenticate using Google, I become a part of it.

But in a average web app I can just do like `hasAuth() ? renderProtected() : renderLoginDialog()` without any redirects.

Tutorial for react router is showing example with redirects, and materials for server-side frameworks is about to do the same.

Is there any practical benefits (like security) of redirect based solution, or it's just following the trend from the giants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common implementation of [Single sign-on - SSO](http://Single%20sign-on%20(SSO)%20is%20an%20authentication%20scheme%20that%20allows%20a%20user%20to%20log%20in%20with%20a%20single%20ID%20and%20password%20to%20any%20of%20several%20related,%20yet%20independent,%20software%20systems). You basically sign in once in a dedicated server, and then you can access multiple applications which are not related without signing in again. For example, after sighing in to your google account you can access all google applications (gmail, drive, calendar ...)

Comment: Thanks, I understand. The question is: Is there any practical benefits (like security) of SSO, if there's just one app, that handles its users itself.

Comment: It's mostly user experience, it's nice that you login once for many services. Regarding security  I guess that using redirect as its pros and cons, but both solutions are considered valid and secure. If you ask the question on https://security.stackexchange.com they will probably go into more details about the security pros and cons of using redirect